# How to access different elements within an array with 2 parts per item

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

Using this example,

```
cards = ['Ace of Spades':1, '2 of Spades':2, '3 of Spades':3,
        '4 of Spades':4, '5 of Spades':5, '6 of Spades':6,
        '7 of Spades':7, '8 of Spades':8, '9 of Spades':9,
        '10 of Spades':10, 'Jack of Spades':10,
        'Queen of Spades':10, 'King of Spades': 10,
        'Ace of Hearts':1, '2 of Hearts':2, '3 of Hearts':3,
        '4 of Hearts':4, '5 of Hearts':5, '6 of Hearts':6,
        '7 of Hearts':7, '8 of Hearts':8, '9 of Hearts':9,
        '10 of Hearts':10, 'Jack of Hearts':10,
        'Queen of Hearts':10, 'King of Hearts': 10, 'Ace of Clubs':1,
        '2 of Clubs':2, '3 of Clubs':3, '4 of Clubs':4, '5 of Clubs':5,
        '6 of Clubs':6,'7 of Clubs':7, '8 of Clubs':8, '9 of Clubs':9,
        '10 of Clubs':10, 'Jack of Clubs':10,
        'Queen of Clubs':10, 'King of Clubs': 10,
        'Ace of Diamonds':1, '2 of Diamonds':2, '3 of Diamonds':3,
        '4 of Diamonds':4, '5 of Diamonds':5, '6 of Diamonds':6,
        '7 of Diamonds':7, '8 of Diamonds':8, '9 of Diamonds':9,
        '10 of Diamonds':10, 'Jack of Diamonds':10,
        'Queen of Diamonds':10, 'King of Diamonds': 10]
```

How could I access the number value corresponding to the card type?  I am making a few card games and I need to create loops to count the numbers (right of semi colon) to get a total value.  I am new to programming but anything you guys can offer would be great!!

For example, how can I point to 1 in Ace of spades? I understand you can point to an item in an array with `[]` but this is an item within an item in an array.
I got this example from another post and im asking what the number to the right of each string is, and how to call it. Normally, you would call an element like x = cards[0] which directs towards Ace of Spades : 1. What I am asking if there is a way to call the number 1 only and not the ace of spades. When I type the code into an editor the numbers to the right of the semi colon are registers as numbers so is this considered a 2D array? Sorry for the confusion, again I am new at programming so anything you guys could offer would be amazing

Comment: This is not valid Python. Please [edit] to fix it (i.e. add your actual data). Maybe it's supposed to be a dict or a list of dicts? See [mre] and [ask] for reference.

Comment: Regardless of the invalid code, make a `Card` class and have a list of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the code to this

```
cards = ['Ace of Spades',1],[ '2 of Spades',2],[ '3 of Spades',3],[
        '4 of Spades',4],[ '5 of Spades',5],[ '6 of Spades',6],[
        '7 of Spades',7],[ '8 of Spades',8],[ '9 of Spades',9],[
        '10 of Spades',10],[ 'Jack of Spades',10],[
        'Queen of Spades',10],[ 'King of Spades', 10],[
        'Ace of Hearts',1],[ '2 of Hearts',2],[ '3 of Hearts',3],[
        '4 of Hearts',4],[ '5 of Hearts',5],[ '6 of Hearts',6],[
        '7 of Hearts',7],[ '8 of Hearts',8],[ '9 of Hearts',9],[
        '10 of Hearts',10],[ 'Jack of Hearts',10],[
        'Queen of Hearts',10],[ 'King of Hearts', 10],[ 'Ace of Clubs',1],[
        '2 of Clubs',2],[ '3 of Clubs',3],[ '4 of Clubs',4],[ '5 of Clubs',5],[
        '6 of Clubs',6],['7 of Clubs',7],[ '8 of Clubs',8],[ '9 of Clubs',9],[
        '10 of Clubs',10],[ 'Jack of Clubs',10],[
        'Queen of Clubs',10],[ 'King of Clubs', 10],[
        'Ace of Diamonds',1],[ '2 of Diamonds',2],[ '3 of Diamonds',3],[
        '4 of Diamonds',4],[ '5 of Diamonds',5],[ '6 of Diamonds',6],[
        '7 of Diamonds',7],[ '8 of Diamonds',8],[ '9 of Diamonds',9],[
        '10 of Diamonds',10],[ 'Jack of Diamonds',10],[
        'Queen of Diamonds',10],[ 'King of Diamonds', 10]
```

and now you can access to only the number doing this

```
number0 = cards[0][1]
numberN = cards[N][1]
```

A better way to do this is using a dictionary

```
cards = {
  "Ace of Spades": "1",
  "King of Diamonds": "10",
  "Jack of Hearts": 10
}
print(cards["Ace of Spades"])
```